# ExposedDropdownMenuBox is not opening the second time when it's clicked

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The ExposedDropdownMenuBox fails to open the second time when clicked, although it functions properly on the first click.

The Same code works 100% if i didnt use viewModel

Compose Code

```
@Composable
fun Input(viewModel: InputViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                .weight(1f),
            expanded = viewModel.expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { viewModel.expanded = it }
        )
        {
            OutlinedTextField(
                label = { Text("Duration") },
                value = viewModel.selectedTermOption.toString(),
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = viewModel.expanded) },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .menuAnchor()
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .exposedDropdownSize(),
                expanded = viewModel.expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { viewModel.expanded = false }
            ) {
                TermOption.entries.forEach { item ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = item.toString()) },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.setTermOption(item)
                            viewModel.expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel Code

```
class InputViewModel : ViewModel()
{
    var selectedTermOption by mutableStateOf(TermOption.YEARS)
    var expanded by mutableStateOf(false)
    init {
        setTermOption(selectedTermOption)
    }
}
```

In the tab layout, the menu opens on the first click, but it doesn't open on the second click.

Comment: There is something wrong with my viewmodel code. i cant find it till now

Answer (score 0):

I successfully edited the code by transferring the VM code into a Kotlin file, and it seems to be functioning as a temporary solution:

```
var selectedTermOption by mutableStateOf(TermOption.YEARS)
var expanded by mutableStateOf(false)

@Composable
fun Input() {
    // Your Composable function implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per jetpack compose guidlines , you don't need to save the call to action states in states in the viewmodel

> (drop down in this case, dialog,popups,bottom sheets states) can be stored inside of compose

```
val dropDownState by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
```

this practice increase the ram usage in long run,
however ,

*the problem you faced is may caused by ,the dependency injection*

you can fix this issue by injecting a single instance of the same viewmodel all over the app,
i attach a image from dagger hilt docs.

[image: this image from dagger hilt docs.]

better instantiate viewmodel in activity class or navhost composable,
and pass it inside of every constructor parameter in composables